# Webscraping google search results Python

Tags: python, python-requests, urllib, python-requests-html

I am trying to obtain both the title and link in some form of list or dictionary of the search results for the first page. However, my output shows `Element 'a' href=` before the link and my title shows `Element 'h3' class=('LC20lb', 'MBeuO', 'DKV0Md')` instead of the actual title. I have read through many examples but most offer API subscriptions that aren't preferable, nor does the beautifulsoup methods that i have searched for works either. This is the furthest I've got with this project so far. My code is below:

```
import requests
import urllib
import pandas as pd
from requests_html import HTML
from requests_html import HTMLSession



def get_source(url):
    """Return the source code for the provided URL. 

    Args: 
        url (string): URL of the page to scrape.

    Returns:
        response (object): HTTP response object from requests_html. 
    """

    try:
        session = HTMLSession()
        response = session.get(url)
        return response

    except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
        print(e)

def scrape_google(query):

    query = urllib.parse.quote_plus(query)
    response = get_source("https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=" + query)

    links = list(response.html.absolute_links)
    google_domains = ('https://www.google.', 
                      'https://google.', 
                      'https://webcache.googleusercontent.', 
                      'http://webcache.googleusercontent.', 
                      'https://policies.google.',
                      'https://support.google.',
                      'https://maps.google.')

    for url in links[:]:
        if url.startswith(google_domains):
            links.remove(url)

    return links


def get_results(query):
    
    query = urllib.parse.quote_plus(query)
    response = get_source("https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=" + query)
    
    return response

def parse_results(response):
    
    css_identifier_result = ".MjjYud"
    css_identifier_title = "h3.LC20lb.MBeuO.DKV0Md"
    css_identifier_link = ".yuRUbf a"
    
    results = response.html.find(css_identifier_result)

    output = []
    
    for result in results:

        item = {
            'title': result.find(css_identifier_title, first=True),
            'link': result.find(css_identifier_link, first=True)
        }
        
        output.append(item)
        
    return output

def google_search(query):
    response = get_results(query)
    return parse_results(response)

results = google_search("Elon Musk twitter")
results
```

Output:

```
[{'title': <Element 'h3' class=('LC20lb', 'MBeuO', 'DKV0Md')>,
  'link': <Element 'a' href='https://www.theguardian.com/technology/2022/oct/30/twitter-trolls-bombard-platform-after-elon-musk-takeover' data-jsarwt='1' data-usg='AOvVaw3lmUr0p6yL70Nhr1Y5jurH' data-ved='2ahUKEwjA9-TFw4j7AhX3QzABHVyyBwcQFnoECBgQAQ'>}]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `BeautifulSoop` library to parse your library better